# Singleton is running again and again in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add some entitites of my model to database when my Laravel app is run for the first time. For this purpose I use singleton:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(InitializeRoles::class, function() {
        return new InitializeRoles();
    });
}
```

And my InitializeRoles.php:

```
class InitializeRoles
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        \App\Role::create(['name' => 'owner'])->save();
        \App\Role::create(['name' => 'moderator'])->save();
    }

}
```

But, however, when the queries to the database added, the next time I refresh my website I get `Duplicate entry 'owner' for key` error, because the `name` field is unique. Why the instances of the Role model are being created again and again? Why the singleton class is not being run only once?

Comment: You have to write this code out of the `__construct()`

Comment: every time the framework is booted all that code is ran again (every request) ... if you want to run a seeder just run a seeder after you migrate your database

Comment: @lagbox thank you for your explanation. But what if it was not a seeding function, but connection to the 3rd-party app API? I suppose the request would be sent again and again.

Comment: you could register your service to the api then boot it to configure it; doesn't mean you are actually making a request every time it boots ... your connections to the database are configured and setup every time you boot but if you don't use the connection it isn't actually connected, etc